# OpenSSH server, what to use for the ip?

Tags: ssh

So I have a bash program in which one of the functionalities of the program is to enable remote connection with SSH. The problem is that this program is suppose to work on any computer/network so I'm not sure what to have as the ip.

My goal is that you simply write (program name) -StartSSH and it is ready for connection.

To summarize: I want to enable connections from remote computers and can I do this without knowing what ip the user will have?

Comment: Could you please be more specific what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Keywords that may help you: you want to run an ssh server. When the ssh server runs, it listens on a given port for attempts to connect (from any IP address, unless you've set your firewall to block certain IP addresses from attempting to connect).

Comment: Oh, so It doesnt require an ip at all? I just install it and people can connect?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the `ListenAddress` to be `0.0.0.0` to use all the IPv4 addresses of the host. This is the default,